# Flutter - slider does not moving when value updated programaticaly

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with a slider on flutter.  the idea in a widget is that first building widget, then I updating values thought method _initFlowRecordFromRoute. _initFlowRecordFromRoute then read the value from ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments and save it. Then I use SetState for updating values in a form.
Everything is working fine ... no problem in TextFormFied (StyledInput), Slide´s is are on correct value but **sliders are not moving**.
It seems like a problem is related to changing the value of the slider programmatically.

Problematic widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/flow_record.dart';
import '../consts/consts.dart';
import '../widgets/styled_input.dart';
import '../services/db_self_improve_servicce.dart';

class EditFlowRecordScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/editFlowrecord';

  @override
  _EditFlowRecordScreenState createState() => _EditFlowRecordScreenState();
}

class _EditFlowRecordScreenState extends State<EditFlowRecordScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _text1 = TextEditingController();
  final _text2 = TextEditingController();
  final _text3 = TextEditingController();
  final _values = [50.0, 50.0, 50.0];
  FlowRecord _flowRecor;

  void _initFlowRecordFromRoute() {
    _flowRecor = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as FlowRecord;
    setState(() {
      _text1.text = _flowRecor.record1;
      _text2.text = _flowRecor.record2;
      _text3.text = _flowRecor.record3;
      _values[0] = _flowRecor.record1val > 0 ? _flowRecor.record1val : 0;
      _values[1] = _flowRecor.record2val > 0 ? _flowRecor.record2val : 0;
      _values[2] = _flowRecor.record3val > 0 ? _flowRecor.record3val : 0;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildTextAreaWithRatioForm(
    TextEditingController text,
    int valueIndex,
  ) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8, left: 8, right: 8),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          StyledInput(
            label: 'Happy thing ${valueIndex + 1}',
            controller: text,
            color: SelfImpruveConsts.mainColor,
            validator: (value) => null,
            minLine: 2,
            maxLine: 30,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Slider.adaptive(
            value: _values[valueIndex],
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            divisions: 100,
            activeColor: SelfImpruveConsts.mainColor,
            label: _values[valueIndex].round().toString(),
            onChanged: (double value) {
              setState(() {
                _values[valueIndex] = value;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _submit() {
    _flowRecor.record1 = _text1.text;
    _flowRecor.record2 = _text2.text;
    _flowRecor.record3 = _text3.text;
    _flowRecor.record1val = _values[0];
    _flowRecor.record2val = _values[1];
    _flowRecor.record3val = _values[2];
    DbSelfImproveService.editFlowRecord(_flowRecor);
    return Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _initFlowRecordFromRoute();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Flow Record'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: _submit,
            icon: Icon(Icons.save_outlined),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _buildTextAreaWithRatioForm(_text1, 0),
                _buildTextAreaWithRatioForm(_text2, 1),
                _buildTextAreaWithRatioForm(_text3, 2),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Flow record model:

```
class FlowRecord {
  final String id;
  String record1;
  double record1val;
  String record2;
  double record2val;
  String record3;
  double record3val;
  final DateTime created;
  final String createdBy;

  FlowRecord({
    this.id,
    this.record1,
    this.record1val,
    this.record2,
    this.record2val,
    this.record3,
    this.record3val,
    this.createdBy,
    this.created,
  });

  factory FlowRecord.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map data = doc.data();

    return FlowRecord(
      id: doc.id,
      created: data['created'] != null
          ? DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(data['created'])
          : null,
      createdBy: data['createdBy'],
      record1: data['record1'],
      record2: data['record2'],
      record3: data['record3'],
      record1val: data['record1val'],
      record2val: data['record2val'],
      record3val: data['record3val'],
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks to all of you !!!

EDIT:
The problem was in me being dum. I did call initialize on every build. Initilize always set initial value on every change.

Comment: I think your problem may be your setState() doesn't mutate any values used in build() so the widget returned by _buildTextAreaWithRatioForm() doesn't get marked as dirty and refreshed. Try passing _values as a parameter to _buildTextAreaWithRatioForm() as something like 'localValue' and use that to set the value: on your Slider().

Comment: The problem was in me being dum. I did call initialize on every build. Initialize always set the initial value on every change.